# Mysql shell seems not to dump deterministically. How can I minimise data transfer when rsyncing subsequent dumps?

Tags: mysql, backup, dump, mysql-shell

What I'm trying to do is generate a full dump of my database using mysql shell, like so:

```
util.dumpSchemas(["my_db"], "outdir", {threads:88, bytesPerChunk: "256M"})
```

And then rsync it to a remote nfs share that contains a previous version of the dump. I'd like to minimise the transferred data, so I was hoping mysql shell's dump utility would generate file chunks for old unchanged data in a repeatable manner (i.e. the files would checksum the same). However this has proved not to be the case, and in fact virtually all the files checksum differently after minor table updates.

The [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html) say that the primary key is used to order & chunk the data, so I optimistically thought that any tables with autoincrementing primary keys should dump in a deterministic way. But that appears not to be the case as the produced files don't checksum the same. Maybe it's ordering rows in reverse?

In any case I would love suggestions for how to do this.

Comment: Are you writing to the same NFS directory?  If you have inserted/deleted as little as a single row I think that would throw off all the "chunks" after that.

Comment: 88 CPU threads?  That seems useless -- the process is mostly I/O-bound.  Unless you have RAID striping, 3 might be a practical limit.

Comment: @RickJames That would suggest it's dumping newest rows first. Do you know if that's actually the case, or just speculating? I'm looking for a way to dump oldest rows first, as the vast majority of the chunks would then be unchanged between db dumps

Comment: The number of threads isn't a factor -- I've tried various values and doesn't make a difference to the repeatability of the dump

Comment: DId a different number of threads lead to slower or faster?

Comment: I'm guessing -- I have never heard of `util.dumpSchemas`.

Comment: @RickJames  This URL includes info on util.dumpSchemas  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html     may have real potential.  introduced in MySQL Shell 8.0.21

Comment: @RickJames Mysql shell seems to optimise the number of threads used for chunking & dumping, so specifying a large number just gives it headroom. I've seen it use 20+ threads at the beginning of the dump when there are a lot of unfinished tables that it can parallelise.

Comment: I would expect determinism for the sake of rsync to be at odds with rapid, compressed, paralyzed dumping.  Suggest filing a bug report (feature request) with bugs.mysql.com.